# Select element has no 'options' array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, select

This is doing my head in!

I have a select element with several options, however I cannot manipulate or access any of the options, as apparently the 'options' array does not exist.

I have recreated the problem in a simpler html document: (original project is ASP MVC)

```
<html><head><title>test test test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function checkMenu() {
if( $("#menu").options ) {
    $("#message").text("Success!");
}
else {
    $("#message").text("Fail :<");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="menu" name="menu">
        <option>qwerty</option>
        <option>uiop</option>
        <option>asdf</option>
        <option>ghjkl</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" onclick="checkMenu()">Clicker!</a>
    <div id="message">message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not managed to find any info on this, any tips appreciated.

Comment: Check munch's answer below. It will work for you. The problem you're having is because .options property doesn't exist. What you have to remember about jQuery is it wraps DOM elements. All of its properties are generic, such as val, text, html, etc. .options doesn't exist. You can iterate the items as well with $("menu").each(function(){ //do something to each... });

Comment: Also check out this page for some basic details of working with selects and jQuery:
http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/01/jquery-playing-with-select-dropdownlistcombobox/

Comment: Thanks for the replies, this has cleared it up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if($'#menu option').length > 0) {
    $("#message").text("Success!");
}
else {
    $("#message").text("Fail :<");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` function in jQuery returns the jQuery object, not the underlying DOM element.  If you want to use the underlying DOM element use `$('#menu').get(0)` or `$('#menu')[0]`.  Even better, use the jQuery methods to access the elements attributes or value.

```
var selected = $('#menu').value();
var selectedText = $('#menu option:selected').text();
```